# Ubuntu 15.04, Vino, Does Not Work

Tags: 15.04, vnc, vino

I have a fresh Ubuntu 15.04 Desktop installed and I'm trying to setup Vino/VNC to access my PC remotely.  I have the following vino package installed:

```
root@wxbrew:~# apt-cache policy vino
vino:
  Installed: 3.8.1-0ubuntu5
  Candidate: 3.8.1-0ubuntu5
  Version table:
*** 3.8.1-0ubuntu5 0
       500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/main amd64 Packages
       100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
root@wxbrew:~#
```

My Desktop Sharing Preferences are set to "Allow other users to view your desktop" and "Allow other users to control your desktop"

When I try to connect to my PC from another Windows PC using TightVNC, or UltraVNC, or even Remote Ripple (from my android phone) it always fails with an error about Authentication.

After some searching I found others with similar issues, and some have recommended this trying this:

```
pkill vino
export DISPLAY=:0.0
/usr/lib/vino/vino-server &
gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false
```

But it doesn't seem to work for me! :(  Syslog logs are below.

Please help!

Thanks,
Rob

```
Syslog:
May 18 16:08:27 wxbrew gnome-session[1941]: 18/05/2015 04:08:27 PM [IPv4] Got connection from client 10.10.8.66
May 18 16:08:27 wxbrew gnome-session[1941]: 18/05/2015 04:08:27 PM   other clients:
May 18 16:08:27 wxbrew gnome-session[1941]: 18/05/2015 04:08:27 PM      10.10.8.66
May 18 16:08:27 wxbrew gnome-session[1941]: message repeated 7 times: [ 18/05/2015 04:08:27 PM      10.10.8.66]
May 18 16:08:27 wxbrew gnome-session[1941]: 18/05/2015 04:08:27 PM Client Protocol Version 3.7
May 18 16:08:27 wxbrew gnome-session[1941]: 18/05/2015 04:08:27 PM Advertising security type 18
```

Answer (score 0):

Recent versions of Vino require encryption by default, that unfortunately, virtually nothing else provides!

[This page](http://www.libregeek.org/2014/04/29/getting-remote-access-work-ubuntu-14-04-vino) is one place that will tell you about it and how to fix it.  Basically, you're just turning off the "require-encryption" option in Vino.